# Laravel; Nothing to migrate

Tags: mysql, laravel

This is my Terminal:

```
php artisan migrate   

   INFO  Nothing to migrate.
```

This is my database

[image]

This is my migrations file _create_students_table.php

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('nickname');
        $table->string('birth_date');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('**customers**', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('nickname');
        $table->string('birth_date');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I want to add 'customers' as you can see here. but when I type 'php artisan migrate' in terminal I see Nothing to migrate.

Comment: That migration file has already been run, that's what the message is telling you. Create a new migration for the customers table only or start a fresh migration (will remove all data first!!!)

Comment: @brombeer How can I do that, could you please share command ?

Comment: Create a migration or migrate fresh? Anyway: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message tells you that there are no new migrations.

You have to execute this command

```
php artisan make:migration create_customers_table
```

And inside the file you have to include this

```
Schema::create('**customers**', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('nickname');
    $table->string('birth_date');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('phone');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Then you can run the command again `php artisan migrate` and should now create the table correctly.